# Angular cli outdir location with Windows path variable

Tags: windows, angular, tomcat, angular-cli, path-variables

Is it possible to have in the angular-cli.json outdir property a windows path variable?

I'm trying to set the app outdir path to tomcat webapp directory, without being depedent on the current machine install location.

I tried in angular-cli.json, but no luck (it just creats a folder called **%CATALINA_HOME%**)

```
...
"apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "%CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/myapp",
...
```

I tried setting it in the commandline using the following:

```
ng build  --base-href /myapp/ --deploy-url /myapp/ --output-path %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/myapp
```

But it just fail silently...

Is there a way to accomplish it? Or am I destined to use absolute path to the tomcat folder?

Comment: with console are you using in windows?

Comment: I'm using cmd to run the ng commands. It correctly return​ tomcat location upon echoing the path variable.

Comment: I just tried this ng build --output-path %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/myapp and it's working (echo %CATALINA_HOME% return me an absolute path btw)

Comment: @rick It started returning following after removing the deploy-url and base-href:
`\tomcat-folder/webapps/app2 was unexpected at this time

"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node.exe"  "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng" build --output-path C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat-folder/webapps/app2
`

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to set tomcat home to a directory without spaces and see what happen?